# Why does $-(3e^{-x})(1-x)-(3e^{-x}) = (-3e^{-x})(2-x)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, derivatives

I am looking at an old exam. The first part of the task wants you to differentiate
$$
f(x) = 3xe^{-x},
$$
which is
$$
f'(x) = 3e^{-x}(1-x)
$$
but then, it wants you to differentitate $f'(x)$.

While solving this problem, my answer was similar to the correct answer up until:
$$
f''(x) = -3e^{-x}(1 - x) - 3e^{-x}.
$$
What I did next, was multiplying $-3e^{-x}$ with $(1 - x)$, and then adding $-3e^{-x}$, but the correct answer did this:
\begin{align*}
&-3e^{-x}(1 - x) - 3e^{-x}, \\
&-3e^{-x}(1 - x + 1), \\
&-3e^{-x}(2 - x).
\end{align*}
I can not see how this is correct. When I solved it in geoGebra I only got the answer:

`(((-3) * ((-x) + 1)) * e^((-x))) - (3 * e^((-x)))`

And when I try to find $x$ using geoGebra, I get $x = 2$, which would indicate that
$$
f''(x) = -3e^{-x}(2 - x).
$$
Is the "correct answer" wrong? or am I. And why can you go from:
$$
-3e^{-x}(1 - x) - 3e^{-x}
$$
to:
$$
3e^{-x}(1 - x + 1)?
$$
Am I missing out on something?

**DISCLAIMER** *Sorry if my tags/title/ description is lacking, I do not know the propper expressions in English, so I used a translator, which migth be wrong. Also by differentiate, I mean $f(x) \to f'(x)$, again, sorry if this is not the rigth expression, and also if i formated poorly.* :^(

Comment: Welcome at MSE! You should rather use Latex/Mathjax syntax in your post for mathematical expressions, by placing dollar signs at the beginning and at the end of each expression.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! I took the liberty of reformatting your question, which including changing some things that appeared to be mis-typed. If I got anything wrong, please feel free to edit.

Answer (score 1):

$$-3e^{-x}(1-x)-3e^{-x}=(-3e^{-x})\cdot(1-x)+(-3e^{-x})\cdot(1)$$
$$=(-3e^{-x})\cdot((1-x)+(1))$$
$$=(-3e^{-x})\cdot(2-x)$$
$$=-3e^{-x}(2-x)$$

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is correct:
$$
-3e^{-x}(1-x) - 3e^{-x} = -3e^{-x}(1 - x + 1) = -3e^{-x}(2 - x).
$$
Generally when doing algebra:

- Look for (and factor out) common factors,
- Group like terms,
- Expand (multiply out) only when necessary.